# when generating normally-distributed random values, what is the most efficient way to define the range?

Tags: javascript, math, random, gaussian, normal-distribution

FYI: random == pseudo-random

A. when generating uniformly-random numbers, I can specify a range, i.e.:

```
(Math.random()-Math.random())*10+5
//generates numbers between -5 and 15
```

B. generating a set of random values with a version of Gaussian-esque normal randomness:

```
//pass in the mean and standard deviation
function randomNorm(mean, stdev) {
  return Math.round((Math.random()*2-1)+(Math.random()*2-1)+(Math.random()*2-1))*stdev+mean);
}

//using the following values:
{
  mean:400, 
  standard_deviation:1
  //results in a range of 397-403, or +-range of 3
},
{
  mean:400, 
  standard_deviation:10
  //results in a range of 372-429, or +-range of 30
},
{
  mean:400, 
  standard_deviation:25
  //results in a range of 326-471, or +-range of 75
}
```

each one gives me a range of approximately standard_deviation*(+-3) (assuming I left the program running longer).

C. I can calculate this range as follows:

1. assuming I want a range from 300-500, so var total_range = 200;
2. my mean is 400, my +-range is total_range/2 (var r = 100)
3. so standard_deviation would be r/3 or in this case 33.333.

This seems to be working, but I have no idea what I'm doing with math so I feel like an idiot, this solution feels kludgy and not totally accurate.

My question:
is there some formula that I'm dancing around that can help me here? my requirements are as follows:

1. must be able to define a range of numbers accurately.
2. must be done in JavaScript, as efficiently as possible.

I think maybe I'm close but it's not quite there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Subtracting two random numbers doesn't give you a normal distribution, it will give you numbers that decline linearly on both sides of zero. See the red diagram in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/tvt5K/

To get a good approximation of normal distribution, add six random numbers together. See the green diagram in the fiddle.

So, to get normally distributed random numbers, use:

```
((Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random() + Math.random()) - 3) / 3
```

This method is based on the central limit theorem, outlined as the second method here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Generating_values_from_normal_distribution

Comment: @jared: That's just enough numbers for the approximation to be reasonably close to the actual normal distribution. See this comparison: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Dice_sum_central_limit_theorem.svg where the original code would correspond to `n = 2`

Comment: thanks!

so following that logic here:
http://jsfiddle.net/jareds/D6Nub/

2,3,4,5,6,12 randoms - 2,4,5,6 all generate similar bell curves...so any of these are similar bell curves. I'll keep looking but i think this is my answer. thanks again.

Comment: To get a N(0,1) you must do `*2` instead of `/3` because the variance of [that distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) is `n/12` being `n` the number of added random numbers. Then if you want a particular standard deviation just multiply by it.

Comment: Where I say `*2` it should say `Math.sqrt(2)` because the standard deviation of the 6 random numbers is `sqrt(6/12) = sqrt(1/2)`.

Comment: @rodrigo: Using `*2` instead of `/3` gives you N(-6,6), not N(0,1). I don't understand what you mean by `*2` should say `Math.sqrt(2)`, that would just be a syntax error.

Comment: @Guffa: With N(0,1) I mean a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Yours have mean 0 but standard deviation `Math.sqrt(1/2)/3`, I think. I should say `* Math.sqrt(2)`, of course. I'm aware that the OP is asking about the range of the distribution, not the standard deviation, but I think it would be nice to clear that point, because technically the normal has a (-inf,+inf) range. I would do the desired standard deviation and mean, and then just crop the out-of-range values.

Answer (score 4):

I wanted to have gaussian random numbers between 0 and 1, and after [many tests](http://jsfiddle.net/xx9bh8Lz/1/) (thanks to @Guffa answer too) I found this to be the best:

```
function gaussianRand() {
  var rand = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i += 1) {
    rand += Math.random();
  }

  return rand / 6;
}
```

---

And as a bonus:

```
function gaussianRandom(start, end) {
  return Math.floor(start + gaussianRand() * (end - start + 1));
}
```